# How can I modify SXA search component to search also in the Accordions content?

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm trying to modify Sitecore default behaviour to search also in accordions content. I have checked `Is Displayed in Search Results` at `/sitecore/templates/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Composites/Datasource/Accordion/Accordion Item/Accordion Item/Content` but it's not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things need to be done:

1. Your template needs to inherit from `/sitecore/Templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable`
2. Create Search Scope which will include your custom template. Location for the scopes is `/sitecore/content/TENANT/SITE/Settings/Scopes` and your scope query can look like:

[image]

3. There is one more thing which might be needed if in the future you would like to search in the different locations. On the Settings item, you will find
   `Associated Content` field. Update it in order to search in the different/custom locations.

Comment: Thanks @Dawid Rutkowski. I'm doing something wrong because search is not working.

I have created a new scope with that query build. I have used the item ID of the _Accordions_ inside Data for `location` and the item ID of my _custom template_ for `template`.

`+location:{1F88BD05-6EE5-4A10-8D65-BCC09AE1A00D};+template:{54B4026C-5B98-4C7F-BA41-032CC003226A}`